# pushd not expanding correctly in git alias

Tags: shell-script

I'm writing a git alias that uses the `pushd` command. However, the command doesn't seem to be expanding correctly.

---

### OS

**Edit**  I'm running ubuntu on WSL on Windows 10:

```
$ uname -a
Linux PowerSpecX251 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft #1237-Microsoft Sat Sep 11 14:32:00 PST 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

---

### Question/Problem

I'm using this syntax to create complex-ish scripts for git aliases, which handles subshells and multiple commands okay:

```
diff-stat = ! "f() { git diff --stat=$(tput cols) $1 ; }; f"
scrub = ! "f() { git reset --hard; git clean -f -f -d; }; f"
```

However, I'm getting an error when I create an alias with the `pushd` command in it -- it seems that the argument of the directory isn't getting passed properly:

```
$ grep pushdtest .gitalias
pushdtest = ! "f() { pushd /home; popd; }; f"

$ git pushdtest
 f() { pushd /home; popd; }; f: 1:  f() { pushd /home; popd; }; f: pushd: not found
 f() { pushd /home; popd; }; f: 1:  f() { pushd /home; popd; }; f: popd: not found
fatal: While expanding alias 'pushdtest': ' f() { pushd /home; popd; }; f': No such file or directory
```

I've tried adding quotes, with no luck:

```
$ git pushdtestquotes
 f() { pushd '/home'; popd; }; f: 1:  f() { pushd '/home'; popd; }; f: pushd: not found
 f() { pushd '/home'; popd; }; f: 1:  f() { pushd '/home'; popd; }; f: popd: not found
fatal: While expanding alias 'pushdtestquotes': ' f() { pushd '/home'; popd; }; f': No such file or directory
```

How can I write a git alias that uses the `pushd` command correctly?

Comment: `$SHELL` doesn’t tell you which shell is running, it tells you what the top-most shell in your current stack of shells is (probably your login shell, as defined in your user information *e.g.* in `/etc/passwd`, or in WSL, the default interactive shell).

Comment: @StephenKitt is there a way to find out which shell these commands are running in?

Comment: Add an alias like `ps = !ps && echo` and run `git ps`. (You need two commands so that the shell doesn’t replace itself with `ps`.)

Comment: @StephenKitt I made the alias `shell = ! "gitshell() { ps && echo }; gitshell"`, and I get this `$ git shell \
fatal: Interactive git shell is not enabled. \
hint: ~/git-shell-commands should exist and have read and execute access.` Does that lead to what I'm looking for?

Comment: No, you need the actual `ps` output. Use the alias in my comment, it doesn’t conflict with other `git` commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably failing because your `/bin/sh` doesn’t support `pushd` and `popd` (*e.g.* it’s dash).

You can ensure that `pushd` and `popd` are usable in your aliases by explicitly specifying the shell to use:

```
pushdtest = !bash -c "'f() { pushd /home; popd; }; f'"
```

Comment: does that help? If git spawns a shell to run that function, the directory stack will be specific to that shell, and destroyed when the shell exits... Something like that would need to be a function in the main interactive shell.

Comment: @ilkkachu it works, however it does it